# Decorrelating 3 categorical variables

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, statistics

I have a table of 3 categorical variables (salary, face_amount, and area_code) that I was looking to decorrelate from one another. In other words, I'm trying to find how much of some output can be attributed solely to each one of these variables. So I would want to see how much of this output is due to the salary variable and not the correlated amount of salary with face_amount for example if that makes sense.

I noticed that there is Multiple Correspondence Analysis for this type of problem that will decorrelate the variables, however, the issue I'm having is that I need the original variables and not the ones that are produced from multiple correspondence analysis. I'm very confused as to how to go about analyzing this type of problem and would appreciated any help with this kind of problem.

Sample of data:

```
salary      face_amount     area_code
'1-50'      1000            67
'1-50'      500             600
'1-50'      500             600
'51-200'    2000            623
'51-200'    1000            623
'201-500'   500             700
```

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this kind of problem

Comment: More suitable for stats.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Okay thank you, I will repost there